# Any point Studio Debugger error: Studio is not able to connect to Debugger server

Tags: debugging, anypoint-studio

Debugger not connecting to Anypoint running job: Mule Debugger:
Studio is not able to connect to Debugger server.

1. Installed Anypoint Studio 7.11.1 fresh
2. Created new workspace.
3. Added Http listener, logger, and set payload
4. Set break points
5. Changed debug port from 6666 to 9999, and many others
6. Rebooted
7. Ran debug and watched app deploy successfully
8. Postman send Get request to Mule app completes but no breakpoints
9. 10 minutes later get the error above

Comment: this happens some time. Did you try restarting the studio. If yes try restarting the laptop.

Comment: Why did you change the debug port?

Comment: The default debugger port 6666 is usually blocked by virus scan softwares if installed on your machine. The reason why it actually work for those who use ports any other 4 digit number.But "changing the port is not the solution".I faced this same issue but when i chnages the port it worked later it was giving the same error. so reinstalling Anypoint studio and used a new workspsce fixed this issue to me. Give a try like this

Comment: I've already reinstalled Anypoint studio and created a new workspace, that was point 1 and 2.  Restarting laptop is point 6.  I am looking for something else that I have not already tried. There is already question like this on the board but I could not comment on it because I did not have enough points. Also, I have never got debug to work, not even once.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The community is not clear on the question. The question is how to get Anypoint debugger to work without erroring during startup. The error is Mule Debugger: Studio is not able to connect to Debugger server. The steps above are how to reproduce the problem. You can change the debug port number on the second tab when choosing debug as with mule application configure option which defaults to 6666 but can be changed.

Comment: As a test, I greatly removed computer system environment variables to bare bones ( windows and windows system), rebooted and everything worked. Something bad in my path, like JavaHome, or something else. I need to mark the resolved somehow.

Comment: I had three java paths in my env var path. This should not have been a problem since I was using the embedded Anypoint java but it did, so beware when having a java path defined in your env var path and using Anypoint.

Answer (score 0):

Thx Bob ! It was that, I uninstall all my JAVA and my jdk stuff and it works. Thx for put me on the track.

If that can help other after doing that, when I launch my app the first line are :

```
MULE_HOME is set to E:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.4.0.ee_7.11.0.202201041751\mule
    MULE_BASE is set to E:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.4.0.ee_7.11.0.202201041751\mule
    Found JAVA_HOME = E:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.jdk.v8.win32.x86_64_1.1.1
    --> Wrapper Started as Console
    Java Service Wrapper Standard Edition 64-bit 3.5.45
      Copyright (C) 1999-2021 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
        http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
      Licensed to MuleSoft Inc. for Mule Runtime Enterprise Edition
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my Studio software not connecting to the Debugger server and diff debugger ports like 6666, 9999, and 6669 which didn't help me fix this. I tried installing different versions, from 7.11 to  7.15,  but none of them fixed it.

I finally got it working by doing two things:

I deleted all the Java folders and files on my computer. (Since the studio uses embedded Java)
I tested different active and listening ports. You can do this by running "netstat -an" in your command prompt. I found that using port numbers 5353 and 5050 worked for me.
I hope these steps help you too!